# How to make class ASDoc for MXML file

Tags: apache-flex, mxml, mxmlc

Is there a way to add a class ASDoc for an MXML document similar to the ASDoc for an AS3 class?

MyClass.as ASDoc:

```
/**
 *  This shows up when hovering over the class in Flash Builder. 
 *  The Group class is the base container class for visual elements.
 *  <p>The <code>&lt;s:Group&gt;</code> tag inherits all of the tag 
 *  attributes of its superclass and adds the following tag attributes:</p>
 *
 *
 *  @see spark.components.DataGroup
 *  @see spark.components.SkinnableContainer
 *
 */
public class MyClass extends Group {

}
```

MyClass.mxml ASDoc:

```
<s:Group xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
         xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark">

    <!---
    ASDoc???
    Does this show up when hovering over the class in Flash Builder? 
    A label, text input and button that is used to select a file or a folder

    -->
</s:Group>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible and you are near to the solution:

```
<!--- This shows up when hovering over the class in Flash Builder! -->
<s:Group xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark">
</s:Group>
```

See also: [Documenting MXML files](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WSd0ded3821e0d52fe1e63e3d11c2f44bc36-7ff2.html)